Resizing textboxes based on the text box content in Powerpoint from Python
In a project i'm working on, I fill a PPTX template using jinja with specific information from a dictonary. The fill part works well, but the current problem is that text box size are not updated after being filled, resulting in the text content overflowing from the text box shape. I want to re-position text boxes so that they do not overlap, but it's not possible without the text box correct size.
With python-pptx, I can resize the text to fit the shape, but not the opposite. There are no way to detect the textbox content size, only the original shape size (before being filled).
With a simple macro in VBA, I can fix the size of all shapes in the frame based on their text content size, and running it with Python is possible with win32com.client. However, this solution only works on a machine with Powerpoint installed, and thus can't work in a standard Azure webapp backend like I need here.
Is there a method to either :

Run a macro from a .pptm file and save it after the macro was executed.
Resize all textboxes in a slide based on their text content and saving the result. As a quick precision, modifying the dimensions of one text box seem to update all other text boxes so that their text fit their shapes dimension, meaning reducing the text size which I do not want. Storing their dimensions first, and resizing in a second time, works however

Aspose and UIPath seem to maybe work with this, but I would like to find possible free workaround for this problem.
It seems that macro are not supported with Office365 or Sharepoint, and OfficeScript is limited for Powerpoint. I do not want to run a VM just for this task if possible.
The current VBA script is :
Sub ResizeTextBoxesWithMission()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim textHeight As Double
    Dim textBoxHeight As Double
    Dim textBoxSizes As Collection
    Set textBoxSizes = New Collection

    ' First loop: Calculate text box sizes without resizing
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shape In slide.Shapes
            If shape.HasTextFrame Then
                If Len(shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) > 0 Then
                    ' Check if the name of the shape contains "Mission"
                    ' Get the text height for this text box
                    textHeight = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundHeight
                    textBoxHeight = textHeight + 10 ' Add some padding
                    ' Store the shape's name and calculated height in the collection
                    textBoxSizes.Add Array(shape.Name, textBoxHeight)
                End If
            End If
        Next shape
    Next slide

    ' Second loop: Apply the calculated sizes
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shape In slide.Shapes
            If shape.HasTextFrame Then
                ' Loop through the stored sizes
                Dim i As Long
                For i = 1 To textBoxSizes.Count
                    Dim item As Variant
                    item = textBoxSizes(i)
                    ' Check if the current shape matches the stored name
                    If shape.Name = item(0) Then
                        ' Apply the calculated height
                        shape.Height = item(1)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next shape
    Next slide
End Sub

Thanks a lot. The stack for the backend is Python with FastApi, python-pptx, and jinja

Are they predefined shapes with fixed sizes, or are you dynamically adding them in the script?

The textboxes from the template have a base width and height, around the "code" of this textbox inside the template. When jinja fills the template with the resume information, tue dimensions are kept the same, but the text may overflow on the bottom.
What i would like is that the height of the textbox gets updated with the size of the text that filled it during the template filling process. That's what was done with the PPTX macro.
However, from Python, there is no way to update the height of the textbox as it's inherent to the layout engine of Powerpiint, hence the problem.
